# break в Java выход из цикла

Tags: java, break

```
public class Puzzle4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 30;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
        for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
            x = x + 0;
            y = y - 2;
            System.out.println(y);
            if (x == 6) {
                break;
            }
            x = x + 3;
        }
        y = y - 2;

    }
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

Всем доброго времени! Данный код взят из книги Head First Java. При выполнении данного кода получается вывод в консоль в виде :"6 14". Если взять листик и ручку и выполнить этот код самому то получается ответ :"6 6". Я начал разбираться в чем же причина, и натолкнулся на то что цикл for со значением outer = 2; не запускается. Я изменил break в условии if на х=x-3 (тоесть сделал то же самое что и делал break не давая выполняться строке x=x+3), и получил результат:"6 6". Напрашивается вывод что из-за многократного выхода из цикла посредством оператора break, не запускается цикл. Простите возможно за глупый вопрос, если можно хотелось бы понять в чем причина такого поведения кода.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Где в коде строка `x=x-3`?

Comment: "Если взять листик и ручку и выполнить этот код самому" думаю в этом проблема

Comment: да. я опечатался. уже исправил на x=x+3;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, ты их перепутал:

- `break` завершает цикл целиком
- `continue` завершает тело цикла, но продолжает сам цикл

Comment: спасибо за ответ. да действительно. я просто запутался и рассматривал работу break как continue

Answer (score 3):

Выкиньте `x = x + 0;` это всё равно ничего не даёт, только вносит неразбериху в ваш неокрепший ум.
В таких случаях старайтесь искать проблему поэтапно,шаг за шагом. 
Нормальные люди это делают с 
помощью дебагера... предоставляю вам вариант курильщика.

```
 int x = 0;
    int y = 30;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
        System.out.println("Цикл 1 работает " + outer + " / " + y);
        for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
            System.out.println("Цикл 2 работает " + outer + " / " + y);
            y = y - 2;
            System.out.println("Вычитание y = " + y);
            System.out.println("x==6 ? - " + (x==6));
            if (x == 6) {

                break;
            }

            x = x + 3;
            System.out.println("Сработал конец цикла 2");
        }

        y = y - 2;
        System.out.println("Сработал конец цикла 1");

    }
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

-> Надеюсь это поможет вам понять как устроены вложенные циклы. Придумайте свои метки в выводе в консоль, которые смогут предоставить вам картину.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. я просто запутался и не так рассмотрел работу break.